# Keep only the rows with dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very messy dataframe imported from excel with only some rows containing a date in the first column (index 0, no headers).  How do I drop all the rows that don't contain a date?

Comment: Would be useful to show us what you tried?

Comment: Also, can you provide some sample data and your expected output (See [mcve]). It's hard to imagine what counts as a date and what doesn't without any data.

Comment: `df[df.Date.notnull()]`

Comment: So I've been trying to select where the string contains things that look like dates, ie. df.loc[df[0].str.contains('2017', na=False)] but that method is returning empty df

Comment: Just post a sample of the dataframe and a desired output please.  Also review [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

I would use `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'`, then drop the null dates by indexing:

For example:

```
>>> df
            x  y
0  2011-02-03  1
1           x  2
2           1  3
3  2012-03-03  4

>>> df[pd.to_datetime(df.x, errors='coerce').notnull()]
            x  y
0  2011-02-03  1
3  2012-03-03  4
```

**Note**: This will lead to some problems if you have different date formats in your column

**Explanation**:

using `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'` will look for a date-like string, and return `NaT` (which is null) if it is not found:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.x, errors='coerce')
0   2011-02-03
1          NaT
2          NaT
3   2012-03-03
Name: x, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Therefore, you can get all the non-null values using `notnull`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df.x, errors='coerce').notnull()
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: x, dtype: bool
```

And use that as a mask on your original dataframe

Comment: could the downvoter explain why this is an inadequate answer?

Comment: I also don't understand downvotes here and on other occasions. Of course the answer is guessing the question, but educated. So if you want to blame someone, blame the OP, but not people spending time to explain solutions

Comment: I think as long as all of the formats can be automatically inferred without the `format` arg, `pandas.to_datetime()` will still parse a column with multiple formats without issue. For instance. `df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['03-04-1988', 'Mar. 4, 1988', 'March 4 1988', '03.04.1988', '3/4/88', '03/04/1988']})` will be handled properly.

Comment: @ALollz, agreed, in that case it might work, however consider the dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2011-13-03', '2012-03-13']})`, where the first is YYYY-DD-MM, and the second is YYYY-MM-DD. In this case, it does not parse everything that would be considered "date-like"